# Remove set of options from a drop down list via jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a drop down list created by a CMS that I have no access to source code for. The drop down list provide a set of dates ranging from 1902 - 2040. I would like to remove all dates after a certain point. I know I can use the following jQuery to taget specific dates and remove them:

```
$("#field_22_year option[value='2036']").remove();
```

But what would be the most efficient way to remove a set of numbers, say everything after 1996?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of George Mavritsakis is appropriate.
But you can also did it with:

```
$('#field_22_year option[value]').each(function() {
    if( $(this).attr("value") > 2036 ) { $(this).remove(); };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
$('#field_22_year option[value]').filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("value") > 1996;
}).remove();
```

See here how to use filter here: [Jquery filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-functionindex)

Answer (score 1):

```
function remove_date_after(initial_date){
       $('#field_22_year').children().each(function(){
            if($(this).val() > initial_date)
                   $(this).remove();
       });
}
```

Here initial date is the value from which you want remove the drop down options. For example, you can call as `remove_date_after(1996)`, which will remove all the options with value greater than 1996